# User-CSS and Site Preferences in Opera 42

Tags: opera, css

I was attempting to follow this link's instructions on enabling user CSS / Site Preferences in Opera, but it seems to be out of date and I can't find an area in the settings to do so: http://www.opera.com/docs/usercss/

Is it still possible to configure the site-specific CSS sheets?

Comment: The bit where it says "Last updated for Opera 11.61" should give you a hint... User CSS was for Opera Presto, not Blink.

Comment: I had noticed the 11.61; Is there any equivalent with Blink?

Comment: Is there still a way to do this?